# How to correct this command?

Tags: compiling

I have defined a simple command

`\newcommand{\removedpart}[1]{\iftrue\textcolor{red}{\sout{#1}}\fi}`

to simply remove or show with red line on it for track-changing the manuscript. I change `\iftrue` to `\iffalse` and everything is ok. It compiles but when I want to compile it with `\iftrue`, nothing compiles. It takes me a long time, to replace the command with the actual `\textcolor{red}{\sout{some text and formula}}` which it was before. Is there any way to make it correct so it compiles and works? The following code doesn't compile. 
Error is :

> Missing } inserted.} ... & some text \\hline}

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ulem}
\newcommand{\removedpart}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\sout{#1}}}
%\renewcommand{\removedpart}[1]{} % Uncomment this line to suppress \removedpart output
\begin{document}
\removedpart{Some text} %This works fine. 
\removedpart{$x=y$}     %This doesn't work. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) you are much more likely to get help if you provide a full (but minimal) document that others can copy and test as is without having to add anything. For starters, not everyone might know where `\sout` comes from.

Comment: BTW: after Hood Chatham suggested `\sout` came from `ulem` I have no issues with the `\iftrue` version in my test, but it fails if you include more than one paragraph in the argument to `\removedpart`

Comment: It's a bit scary that your example includes table related characters in the argument. Probably the issue is with `\sout{&}` which looks like a really bad idea to me.

Comment: I just want to have a red line on the text and formula or any thing else which shows it is deleted. Is there any other way to define this command?

Comment: Unfortunately, Undo is not available to when I replaced \textcolor{red}{\sout{text or formula}} with the command. So I have to do it manually from start to the end, which takes me much time.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused why it would have run before you replaced that with this command, because the underlying issue is that you shouldn't be putting table formatting characters inside of `\sout` or `\textcolor`.

Comment: I you cannot have a construct like that, which spans several cells in a table due to the manner in which the table parser works, in short the & is hidden and everything goes wrong. Apply to dingle cells.

Comment: @daleif, would you please now take a look at question? It doesn't work with formula but works fine with text.

Comment: @user85361 The code your question currently has runs fine on my computer.

Comment: Add example code. We are wasting our time here trying to guess how you're using that macro. Imo better to just use color to mark, not strike through, less things that can go wrong

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a comment? Conditionals are not necessary if you just want to switch the behavior throughout the document. Just define the command to output the text as you want and add a commented out line that redefines the command to output nothing. If you want to switch to outputting nothing, uncomment the redefinition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ulem}
\newcommand{\removedpart}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\sout{#1}}}
%\renewcommand{\removedpart}[1]{} % Uncomment this line to suppress \removedpart output
\begin{document}
The removed part: \removedpart{this displays only if renewcommand is commented out!}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't compile even with your technique.

Comment: would you please take a look at question now. It doesn't work with formula but works fine with text.